# SwiftUI - Error when calling UUID().uuidString id

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, swiftui, uuid

I get this error `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` when I try to use a function like this:

```
func itemId(title: String) -> String {
    var id = UUID()
    for item in itemsCoreData {
        if item.title == title {
            id = item.id
        } else {
            break 
        }
    }
    return id.uuidString
}
```

itemsCoreData is a variable from a fetch request that stores my Core Data objects. item.id is the UUID stored in Core Data of that Object

Comment: Are you sure `item.id` is-a UUID? Would you show CoreData model autogenerated  interface for item type?

Comment: Yeah, the id is a UUID type as well as the NSManaged class property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `first(where:)` method here.

```
func itemId(title: String) -> String? {
    itemsCoreData.first(where: { $0.title == title })?.id.uuidString
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's related to how you're using this method.

Comment: I'm using this method inside the identifier of the local notification. Before that I loop over my json data to extract the titles to display in a list with a button beside that adds that item in Core Data and right after triggers the notification

Comment: I made it by adding a state property to store the current core data entity and as identifier I just used the id on the json + the state property so for the same item I would have the id plus the current core data entity and they will be different each time